# Is there any way to get component from different directory?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create on the fly component in separate project from my main project and have it loaded in runtime. The problem is I don't know how to get the component if its located in different directory.

Here's the idea come from https://denys.dev/2016-11-27/dynamic-content-in-angular/

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'runtime-content',
    template: `
        <div>
            <h3>Template</h3>
            <div>
                <textarea rows="5" [(ngModel)]="template"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button (click)="compileTemplate()">Compile</button>
            <h3>Output</h3>
            <div #container></div>
        </div>
    `
})
```

```js
let metadata = {
            selector: `runtime-component-sample`,
            template: this.template
        };

        let factory = this.createComponentFactorySync(this.compiler, metadata, null);
```

So far what I have is create component based on whatever written inside textarea shown in runtime-content component and put it inside metadata.

```js
private createComponentFactorySync(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component, componentClass: any): ComponentFactory<any> {
        const cmpClass = componentClass || class RuntimeComponent { name: string = 'Denys' };
        const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

        @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
        class RuntimeComponentModule { }

        let module: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any> = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(RuntimeComponentModule);
        return module.componentFactories.find(f => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
    }
```

But what I need is how to create that metadata based on for example some other ts file outside of the project?